# Unable to access Objective-C class instance variables in body of C function

Tags: objective-c, c, function, instance-variables

I have a class `MicController` and give it an instance variable like this:

```
@implementation MicController {
   AudioStreamBasicDescription streamFormat;
}
```

I initialize the object and attempt to create an audio unit using that ASBD variable to keep track of a stream format.

```
- (instancetype)init {
   if (self = [super init]) {
      [self setup];
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)setup {
   CreateInputUnit();
}
```

However, inside `CreateInputUnit()` I seem to have no access to the variable.

```
void CreateInputUnit () {
stream... // nothing
}
```

No auto-completion, no syntax high-lighting, no compilation.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You only have access to instance variables in instance methods. How would your C function know which instance it's supposed to be accessing, for instance? It can't know by magic.

Comment: That makes sense.  I assumed that anything in the `@implementation` block would be in a certain scope where the variables are alive.  But I now see that I must pass in the variables as parameters to use them?  If so, they'd be copies.  Is there a way people access instance variables in c functions traditionally?

Comment: C doesn't have classes or instance variables. To do something comparable in C, you'd generally pass a pointer to a struct, and access the struct members by that. Under the hood, this is pretty much what's going on with an instance method, the language just hides it from you.

Comment: I think you could pass objective-C instance to a C function by reference. Should be like `void CreateInputUnit(MicController *controller) { ... }`?

Comment: Instance variables defined in the implementation section are private to the class.  If you moved the declaration to the `@interface` section, you'd be able to use the struct pointer access operator `->` to reach it.  That may actually work with the definition where it is, but the compiler won't like it.

Comment: are you talking about accessing an instance variable declared in the interface block like `self->iVar`?

Comment: I appreciate that several people have responded here.  May I ask why i was down-voted?  I thought I posed the question properly and provided context.

Comment: Wouldn't `@defs()` Approach still work ?

Comment: i'm am not familiar with @def() in the context of c/objective-c

Answer (score 0):

For your class, it is possible to have multiple object instances, or none.  A C function can't know which object (if one even exists) in which to look for instance variables, unless you either (1) pass the object as a parameter, or (2) set a global C variable to a pointer to the instantiation of the object of interest.  The latter (2) is only useful for singleton objects, of course.

Given a pointer to an object passed to the C function, you can use the struct dereference operator ("->") to access any instance variable in the object that was declared in the class interface.  Or you can just pass the data or pointers of interest directly.

Comment: Can 1 pass the iVar also by reference ?